# データベースでデータが増え続けるテーブルの管理の仕方について

Tags: mysql, postgresql, データベース設計

MySQLを使ったリレーショナルデータベースを想定しています。

例えば掲示板のようなデータベースでユーザーがどんどんポストしていくもので、消すわけにはいかないものはどのように管理するのがよいのでしょうか。

インデックスを貼ったりしても、肥大化し続けるとどこかで辛くなって行くのではないかと心配です。

思いつく対策としては、`posts-2016`というようにテーブルを1年毎に分割していくやり方ですが、なにか定石はあるのでしょうか。

Comment: どういう種類のアプリケーションか不明ですが、掲示板だったら、某ちゃんねるのようなテキストやhtmlにエクスポートして、量が多ければgzipなどしてしまうのもありかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/partitioning.html)にも[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.5/html/ddl-partitioning.html)にも指定された条件で分割されたテーブルを扱うパーティショニングという機能があります。

本当に必要かどうかはデータ量などを見積もった上で検討してください。

Answer (score -1):

求めている回答とは違うのかもしれませんが、別サーバーを立て、ＳＱＬやＯｒａｃｌｅなどを使用して運用しています。サーバーの容量にも限界がありますので、やはりどこかで見切って削除します。